# Когда остановится цикл?

Tags: c++, c, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
double x=1; 
while( x+1>x ) 
x++;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если тип `double` — это число с плавающей точкой формата [`IEEE 754 binary64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (в большинстве случаев так и есть), то возможны по крайней мере три следующих ответа.

1. `2^53 == 9007199254740992.0`

При достижении значения `2^53` цикл остановится, т.к. в числах с плавающей точкой `2^53 + 1 == 2^53`.

Все целые числа из отрезка `[-2^53, 2^53]` типом `double` представимы точно. Следующее вещественное число после `2^53` представимое типом `double` — это `2^53 + 2`. Их битовые паттерны (различие всего лишь в самом младшем бите мантиссы):

```
2^53     == 0 | 10000110100 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2^53 + 2 == 0 | 10000110100 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Точный вещественный результат `2^53 + 1` будет округлён до одного из двух чисел с плавающей точкой, между которыми он находится.

По умолчанию, используется режим округления «до ближайшего». Если точный результат находится точно посередине между двух чисел с плавающей точкой, то будет выбрано то, младший бит мантиссы которого равен нулю. В данном случае `2^53 + 1` округляется до `2^53`.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << std::fixed;
    
    double x = 9007199254740992.0 - 4.0; 
    while( x+1 > x ) {
        cout << "x:    " << x << endl;
        x++;
    }
    cout << "last: " << x << endl;
    
    double t1 = 9007199254740992.0;
    double t2 = t1 + 1.0;
    cout << "t1:   " << t1 << endl;
    cout << "t2:   " << t2 << endl;
}
```

[Вывод](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d62408975810e6d):

```
x:    9007199254740988.000000
x:    9007199254740989.000000
x:    9007199254740990.000000
x:    9007199254740991.000000
last: 9007199254740992.000000
t1:   9007199254740992.000000
t2:   9007199254740992.000000
```

---

2. `+inf`

Среди возможных режимов округления точного результата до числа с плавающей точкой, определяемых стандартом `IEEE 754`, есть режим округления «в сторону положительной бесконечности».

При данном режиме округления условие `x+1 > x` будет выполняться, пока переменная `x` не равна `NaN` или `±inf`

Данный режим можно включить, используя функцию [`std::fesetround()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround).

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << std::scientific;
    cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
    
    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    
    double x = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        x = std::nextafter(x, 0.0);
    while( x+1 > x ) {
        cout << "x:    " << x << endl;
        x++;
    }
    cout << "last: " << x << endl;
    
    double t1 = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double t2 = t1 + 1.0;
    cout << "t1:   " << t1 << endl;
    cout << "t2:   " << t2 << endl;
}
```

[Вывод](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f25d7c4fd1796d9) (g++ с использованием опции `-frounding-math`. Без данной опции компилятор предполагает, что всегда используется режим округления по умолчанию.):

```
x:    1.79769313486231511e+308
x:    1.79769313486231531e+308
x:    1.79769313486231551e+308
x:    1.79769313486231571e+308
last: inf
t1:   1.79769313486231571e+308
t2:   inf
```

3. Бесконечный цикл

Стандарт языка допускает, что результат выражения в числах с плавающей точкой может иметь большую точностью (precision) и диапазон (range), чем того требует результирующий тип. [`expr.pre/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#6):

> The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.47
>
> 47. The cast and assignment operators must still perform their specific conversions as described in [expr.type.conv], [expr.cast], [expr.static.cast] and [expr.ass].

Например, в следующем коде

```
double x = ...;
bool   b = x + 1 > x;
```

результат выражения `x + 1` имеет тип `double`, но точность и диапазон у результирующего значения могут быть больше, чем у типа `double`.

Иными словами, вполне возможно, что точный вещественный результат выражения `x + 1` будет округлён не до типа `double`, а до некоторого более ёмкого, чем `double` типа.

На практике такое возможно, если вычисления производятся в [модуле операций с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80) (*floating point unit* (*FPU*)), производящем вычисления в [80-битных числах с плавающей точкой](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision).

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << std::fixed;
    
    int counter = 0;
    volatile double tmp = 9007199254740992.0 - 4.0;
    double x = tmp;
    while( x+1 > x ) {
        cout << "x:    " << x << endl;
        x++;
        counter++;
        if (counter > 8) {
            cout << "counter break!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "last: " << x << endl;
}
```

[Вывод](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec8212219c2169d5) (g++ с использованием опции -mfpmath=387 для того, чтобы вычисления производились в FPU):

```
x:    9007199254740988.000000
x:    9007199254740989.000000
x:    9007199254740990.000000
x:    9007199254740991.000000
x:    9007199254740992.000000
x:    9007199254740992.000000
x:    9007199254740992.000000
x:    9007199254740992.000000
x:    9007199254740992.000000
counter break!
last: 9007199254740992.000000
```

Начиная со значения `2^53 == 9007199254740992.0`, инкремент переменной `x` на единицу не изменяет её значения, но при этом условие цикла `x+1 > x` оценивается с расширенной точностью 80-битного FPU. Т.е. точный вещественный результат `2^53 + 1` не округляется до `2^53` при оценке условия цикла, следовательно выражение `x+1 > x` оказывается истинным. Это бесконечный цикл!

Comment: а можете с таким помочь вопросом double x=1.0;
do
{
x/=2.0;
}
while( 1.0+x>1.0 );
}

Comment: такой цикл когда остановится

Comment: Наглядная демонстрация сложности *вычислительной математики* (+)